# Convert to % for a count SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT DEL_CD ,COUNT(DEL_CD) AS COUNT_NO
FROM [DATAStaging].[dbo].[DATASTORE]
GROUP BY DEL_CD
```

gives me this result

```
DEL_CD     COUNT_NO
0           6442
1           12161
2           2342
```

But what do I have to do to the script to display the count number as a %

Total rows does = sum of count_no.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT   del_cd, COUNT(DEL_CD) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(DEL_CD)) OVER ()
FROM     datastore
GROUP BY
         del_cd
```